# no org.junit.test package in maven junit 4.5

Tags: java, maven, junit

i have a maven dependency for junit version 4.5 and want to use @test announciation but cant because the artifact does not have org.junit.test package in it. Why is that so and how can i use @test with maven artifact?

Comment: It's called `@Test`, not `@test`.

Comment: There is no package org.junit.test, but an annotation org.junit.Test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fully qualified class is `org.junit.Test`. It's definitely in there.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

A test:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ThisIsATest {

    @Test
    public void method() {
        Assert.assertTrue("OMG test!", true);
    }

}
```